# How to add Custom Fields in CKAN dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2, ckan

I have tried to add extrafield extension in `CKAN.but` while I am adding

```
ckan.plugin = extrafields
```

I am getting error such as:

> ckan.plugins.core.PluginNotFoundException: extrafields

also I have used this [Ckanext extrafields](https://github.com/ubdc-IT/ckanext-extrafields)

Anyone can help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you install the extension in your virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the extension is installed.

Make sure you are in your virtualenv, and then do to the ckanext-extrafields directory and do:

`python setup.py install`

or if you're doing development

`python setup.py develop`